# JuliaSetPlot increase quality of output

Tags: plotting, visualization, fractals

For a complex dynamics class I take I want to generate a nice image of an Herman ring. I used this code to generate a first image:

```
g[z_] = (Exp[2*Pi*I*(-3.57)]*z^2*(z - 4))/(1 - 4 z);

JuliaSetPlot[
  g[z], z,
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 8}, {-4, 4}},
  ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}
]
```

[image]

It looks more or less great but it seems that Mathematica does not care about `ImageSize` since the image wont increase the amount of detail in it with higher resolutions. Also I would like to get a control over the number of iterations so I can increase them. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you already tried increasing the `ImageResolution` setting, as noted in the docs?

Comment: `MaxIterations -> 200` has some effect. (Explore the options in the docs.)

Comment: Also use `ImageSize -> 1000` rather than `ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}` to avoid dead space at the top and bottom of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did look at the docs but I always looked under 'Options' and totally overlooked 'Details and Options'. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If it solves the problem perhaps you can write an answer for others who may find this in the future.